# How do i get input from echo in terminal?

Tags: c, terminal

For example, when you want to get input from user in Java, you simply use `Scanner in = new Scanner`, now I want to get input from user which is gonna input using echo command, such as `echo 2 3 | sh addition`, what C commands do I put in my script so that it reads the 2 and 3? Thanks!

Comment: Step one is to learn the language. Here's a [list of books](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/3386109) to help you get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `C`

`echo 2 3 | sh addition` basicially means "input `2`, a space and `3` into the command `sh addition`", which means you should be able to read `2` and `3` in your program as it is manually typed in.

However, `sh addition` means excuting a shell script which is not C. A C program could be excuted directly with its file name, i.e. `./a.out` where `a.out` is your program. So the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
    return 0;
}
```

Should do what you want. After you compile it to a excutable, for example `a.out`, you can run it by

```
echo 2 3 | ./a.out
```

### Shell script

`sh addition` means run a shell script. To write a shell script you write something like this in a file named `addition` which you will be able to run using `sh addition` or `echo 1 2 | sh addition`.

```
#!/bin/sh

read a b # read two int, one put in a and another put in b.
echo -n "$a + $b = ";
expr $a + $b
```

`read` is just like `scanf`, and `expr` do calculation and output.

Comment: hmm thanks, i thought writing in vim is the same as c.. if I want to do `sh filename`, what do I need to modify? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant "what C instructions should I use in my **C program** to read standard input"...Ok?

Well... you can use several instructions to read your standard input. I guess you might want to start using scanf(). Something like this:

```
... all includes, declarations, etc. here ...
scanf ( "%d %d", &a, &b ) ;
// a and b are the two integer variables where you will store 2 and 3
...
```

Comment: i thought writing in vim is the same as c.. if I want to do sh filename, what do I need to modify? thanks again!

Comment: I do not understand. Vim is an editor. C is a programming language and shell is a totally different stuff.